# User input has multiple validation conditions

Tags: c#, user-input

I'm trying to write something basic to validate a user's input. Such as, the user input must be a string of any length that has only certain characters (like the @, a dash, an underscore, letters, and numbers), like an email address, and that they're in a certain order.

I have been considering a while loop, like the one below, so it loops until the conditions are met. But I'm not sure how to define the conditions, if `if` statements are useful or not. Is there a datatype, like DateTime, that can be used to see if the input is valid? I'm new to OOP, so this is one is tripping me up. Thanks!

```
public string input;
while (true)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Enter Email");
     input = Console.ReadLine();
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Email was not valid");
     }
     else if (condition)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Email was not valid");
     }
     else
     {
          return input;
     }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use regex for matching if input has all necessary characters and doesn't contain forbidden ones.

Comment: _"I have been considering a while loop"_ - you don't need a loop (unless you want to re-implement a poor-man's regex engine using a DFA state-machine). Everything you've listed in your post is doable with a single `Regex`.

Comment: Use a `for` loop to loop through all characters and then check uf each of the character is valid or not, using regex as @1_bug said